# Stop "Grant permission to Chrome Remote Desktop" from appearing

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, remote-desktop

I downloaded Chrome Remote Desktop on my MacBook Pro, Early 2013, macOS Catalina v10.15.4 about a week ago. When doing so, I gave it all the requested permissions to work on Settings including Screen Recording. I automatically log into my gmail account on Google Chrome when opening Chrome, which I use as my main browser.

Since downloading Chrome Remote Desktop, every time I switch on my Mac, this message appears, requesting the Screen Recording permission. It does not matter whether I cancel, or untick and retick the permission; the message will appear again the next time.

Is it possible to stop this message from recurring?

[image: e]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a similar problem the past few days. I used it for years without this problem. Now, no matter what I try, the "screen recording permission" dialog keeps coming back after a little while. Even if I am doing nothing on my Mac. My guess is either Apple or Google broke something with a recent update.

I tried:

- rebooting
- clicking the permission off and on
- clicking the permission off and on, while the lock is open
- re-initiating it from Chrome

My (temporary) solution is to move the dialog out of the way.

macOS 10.15.4

Chrome 80.0.3987.149

Chrome Remote Desktop 1.5

**EDIT:** The latest Chrome update fixed the problem. No more problems!

Chrome 80.0.3987.163

Comment: Do you recall which update made this happen? Moving the dialog out of the way seems odd when you can close it

Comment: @Mborg, the problem is that if you close the dialog it automatically opens again after a little while. I now completely removed Chrome Remote Desktop from my Mac to get rid of this highly annoying problem. The versions I use are macOS 10.15.4, Chrome 80.0.3987.149 and Chrome Remote Desktop 1.5. I got this problem recently so it is one of those.

Comment: When I close it, it only reappears after I reset the computer. By update, I was referring to your 'recent update.' You had used it for years without problem, but the problem would have started after that recent update. Like for example, it happened when you updated to macOS 10.15.4, before or after you updated Chrome and Chrome Desktop.

Comment: I don't know what update triggered the problem. I no longer have the problem with the latest Chrome update.

Comment: I also don't have the problem as of late. That Chrome update solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue that it pops up every time I reboot my MacBook Pro.

I found the solution which worked for me.

Press Command + space and type "Chrome Remote Desktop Host Uninstaller" and launch it. I rebooted my Mac to see if it pops up again and finally it's gone.

Hope that works for you as well :D

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because of an old program that used the remote desktop feature, and *nothing* I tried stopped the popup from showing on startup. I don't want the permission to be enabled, so enabling it isn't an option for me.

After having gone through the below steps, I finally gave up and enabled the permission. But after restarting to see if I could disable it again, it was no longer an accessibility option.

Here's what I did:

1. Completely removed the original old program that used the Remote Desktop feature
2. Completely dropped any device from the Remote Desktop feature (you can drop devices here: https://remotedesktop.google.com/access
3. Completely removed Chrome and settings/config, then reinstalled latest stable (v88.0.4324.182)
4. Removed Chrome personalization (the account sync feature)

Finally.. I gave up and enabled the feature (follow the prompted steps in the popup). I then restarted to see if I could disable again, but the option was gone. Operation failed successfully I guess!

Answer (score 0):

The issue appeared when I upgraded from macOS Catalina to Monterey.

What solved the issue for me was to add (+) "/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/ChromeRemoteDesktopHost.app/Contents/MacOS/NativeMessagingHost.app" in the "Settings | Security & Privacy | Privacy | Screen Recording" pane.

I.e. NativeMessagingHost.app instead of the ChromeRemoteDesktopHost.app/ <-- which was "filled in" by the remote desktop host installer.